# Equal sums of powers of two disjoint sets

Tags: number-theory

Here are two disjoint sets of natural numbers consisting of 128 elements s.t. 
the sums of the $j$-th powers of their members for $j$ from $1$ to $7$ are equal:

$$L:= \left\{ 1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16,18,19,21,24,25,28,30,31,34,35,37,40,41,44
,46,47,49,52,54,55,58,59,61,64,66,67,69,72,73,76,78,79,81,84,86,87,90,
91,93,96,97,100,102,103,106,107,109,112,114,115,117,120,121,124,126,
127,130,131,133,136,137,140,142,143,145,148,150,151,154,155,157,160,
161,164,166,167,170,171,173,176,178,179,181,184,185,188,190,191,193,
196,198,199,202,203,205,208,210,211,213,216,217,220,222,223,226,227,
229,232,233,236,238,239,241,244,246,247,250,251,253,256 \right\}  
$$
and
$$M:=\{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 17, 20, 22, 23, 26, 27, 29, 32, 33, 36, 38, 39, 42, 43, 45, 48, 50, 51, 53, 56, 57, 60, 62, 63, 65, 68, 70, 71, 74, 75, 77, 80, 82, 83, 85, 88, 89, 92, 94, 95, 98, 99, 101, 104, 105, 108, 110, 111, 113, 116, 118, 119, 122, 123, 125, 128, 129, 132, 134, 135, 138, 139, 141, 144, 146, 147, 149, 152, 153, 156, 158, 159, 162, 163, 165, 168, 169, 172, 174, 175, 177, 180, 182, 183, 186, 187, 189, 192, 194, 195, 197, 200, 201, 204, 206, 207, 209, 212, 214, 215, 218, 219, 221, 224, 225, 228, 230, 231, 234, 235, 237, 240, 242, 243, 245, 248, 249, 252, 254, 255\} $$
Here is the verification of that statement with Maple:

```
L := {1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 16, 18, 19, 21, 24, 25, 28, 30, 31, 34, 35, 37, 40, 41, 44, 46, 47, 49, 52, 54, 55, 58, 59, 61, 64, 66, 67, 69, 72, 73, 76, 78, 79, 81, 84, 86, 87, 90, 91, 93, 96, 97, 100, 102, 103, 106, 107, 109, 112, 114, 115, 117, 120, 121, 124, 126, 127, 130, 131, 133, 136, 137, 140, 142, 143, 145, 148, 150, 151, 154, 155, 157, 160, 161, 164, 166, 167, 170, 171, 173, 176, 178, 179, 181, 184, 185, 188, 190, 191, 193, 196, 198, 199, 202, 203, 205, 208, 210, 211, 213, 216, 217, 220, 222, 223, 226, 227, 229, 232, 233, 236, 238, 239, 241, 244, 246, 247, 250, 251, 253, 256 }:
seq(add(map(c -> c^j, L)), j = 1 .. 7);
16448, 2812608, 541073408, 111027700800, 23732020748288, 5217614623395648, 1171017999358189568
M := {2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 17, 20, 22, 23, 26, 27, 29, 32, 33, 36, 38, 39, 42, 43, 45, 48, 50, 51, 53, 56, 57, 60, 62, 63, 65, 68, 70, 71, 74, 75, 77, 80, 82, 83, 85, 88, 89, 92, 94, 95, 98, 99, 101, 104, 105, 108, 110, 111, 113, 116, 118, 119, 122, 123, 125, 128, 129, 132, 134, 135, 138, 139, 141, 144, 146, 147, 149, 152, 153, 156, 158, 159, 162, 163, 165, 168, 169, 172, 174, 175, 177, 180, 182, 183, 186, 187, 189, 192, 194, 195, 197, 200, 201, 204, 206, 207, 209, 212, 214, 215, 218, 219, 221, 224, 225, 228, 230, 231, 234, 235, 237, 240, 242, 243, 245, 248, 249, 252, 254, 255}:
seq(add(map(c -> c^j, M)), j = 1 .. 7);
16448, 2812608, 541073408, 111027700800, 23732020748288,5217614623395648, 1171017999358189568
```

These relations can be treated as solutions of a certain system of diophantine equations.
How to construct  longer sequences with that properties?

Comment: For longer sequences do you mean for larger $j$ value or larger $|L|+|M|$?

Comment: @Gareth Ma:Thank you for your interest.  I mean larger $|L|=|M|$. Values of $j>7$ are welcome too. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem#Examples).

Comment: @metamorphy: Many thanks from me to you. Can you make an answer in order to accept it? TIA.